# Apply Gnome menu changes system wide

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

I have made changes to my gnome menu, how can I apply Gnome menu changes system wide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just but .desktop entries describing the application in the /usr/share/applications directory. The menu items you created created new .application files in ~/.gnome/apps directory. You can also move those to the system location.

Answer (score 1):

You do so by editing the contents of /usr/share/applications. The .desktop file there defines the gnome attributes that are used to populate the Gnome menu.